# how do i send folder with its contents (subfolder/files) to server-client side?

Tags: c#, client-server, directory

I'm making a file transfer (server-client) application. im using TCP. (.net 4.0)

How do I send a Folder with all its contents(folder/files) to the other side ??

I have these methods that works fine:

```
Send(string srcPath, string destPath)  //sends a single file
```

```
Recieve(string destPath) //recieves a single file
```

This is the Send method:

```
public void Send(string srcPath, string destPath)
{
    using (fs = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        try
        {
            fileSize = fs.Length;
            while (sum < fileSize)
            {
                if (fileSize - sum < packetSize)
                {
                    count = fs.Read(data, 0, (int)(fileSize - sum));
                    network.Write(data, 0, (int)(fileSize - sum));
                }
                else
                {
                    count = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    network.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
                fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                sum += count;
            }
            network.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and this's the Recieve Method :

```
    public void Recieve(string destPath)
    {
        using (fs = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    if (fileSize - sum < packetSize)
                    {
                        count = network.Read(data, 0, (int)(fileSize - sum));
                        fs.Write(data, 0, (int)(fileSize - sum));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = network.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    }
                    fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    sum += count;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a common variables :

```
    const int packetSize = 1024 * 8;    //Packet Size.
    long sum;                           //Sum of sent data.
    long fileSize;                      //File Size.
    int count = 0;                      //data counter.
    static byte[] data = null;          //data buffer.

    NetworkStream network; 
    FileStream fs;
```

I also got:

```
bool IsFolder(string path) //that returns if the path is a folder or a file
```

Comment: You can wrap the directory in an archive (Zip or the like) and send that. Though the server side would need to be changed to handle it that way.

Comment: Does server support this receiving entire folder tree or just file by file?

Comment: send the files one by one is another option (in the same stream - use a separator bw files and slap a header as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the answer

```
public void SendFolder(string srcPath, string destPath)
    {
        string dirName = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(srcPath));
        CreateDirectory(dirName);  // consider that this method creates a directory at the server
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(srcPath);
        string[] subDirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(srcPath);
        foreach (string filePath in fileEntries)
        {
            Send(srcPath, dirName);
        }
        foreach (string dirPath in subDirEntries)
        {
            SendFolder(dirPath, dirName);
        }
    }
```

the server will first create a direcotory .. named the same name of the directory from the client side .. which is dirName

then it will send all the files in that folder ..
then it will recursively do the same for each folder .. problem solved

Answer (score 1):

With a Directory Path can do this :

```
    public void SendAll(string DirectoryPath)
    {

        if (Directory.Exists(DirectoryPath))
            {
                string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath);
                string[] subdirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryPath);

                foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                {
                    Send(fileName);


    }

            foreach (string dirName in subdirEntries)
            {
                SendAll(dirName);
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: oh .. but this's not going to work.. because the server wouldn't put the files in the right subfolders .. the server should create directory and the each file client send should received in the right folder .. there should be a (destination Path)

Comment: it's only to show you how send entire file from a directory path.