# What's the best and secured way to enable winform application to access network files?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I am developing a windows form program in C# .Net and I need it to read and write files from/to a folder on a computer (let's name the computer SERVER_PC) on the wireless network which connects only 5 PCs. Basically, users should not even know about the files outside my program. I mean they shouldn't' read or write files to SERVER_PC directly. only the program should be able to connect to that folder on SERVER_PC and open the files for them.

DO I need to create a home group just for this purpose? Is this a secure way of handling it? Can I grant (read, write) permissions only to my program?
I am running windows 7 on all network PCs

(NOTE: We don't want to use domain controller for this.)

I really appreciate your help. thanks a lot

Comment: Use ftp to access specific folder related to your program files on SERVER_PC

Answer (score 1):

You could have a server app and a client app that transfer files using tcp sockets.

The server could provide a list of filenames to the clients. The clients could then request a file or files, the server then sends them then the user could save them back effectively sending them back to the server app which would then save them.

You could then restrict access to the folders to the user the server app runs under.

You would need to handle issues with more than one person working with a file though, unless you gave each user their own folder.

if you wanted to get more secure, you could encrypt the streams being sent between tcp end points.

Comment: You can use tcp socket for this or you can use some other way to implement communication between two processes running on different machines. Check [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx). Learning how to use tcpsocket is easier than learning WCF, but after that, WCF will offer you an easy way to implement complex task (e.g., call from client program a method `Server.SaveFile(byte[] content, string fileName)` the same way you call a method running in client program)

Comment: why do I have to use sockets when I already have windows library which can copy and open files very easily. currently I am using System.IO.File.Copy to the network folder but maybe I need a guidance on how to secure this so that only my program can use the files.

Comment: In order for File.Copy or open to work directly from the program the user is using you they would need access to the folder and file. As I understood your question, you wanted to provide file access without the user having access to the folders or files outside of your program. The easiest way I could think of was to use tcp sockets. Gian Paolo's idea of using WCF is another option but has a longer learning curve in my opinion.

Comment: .NET Socket class has an overloaded BeginSendFile member method offering a couple options. https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSendFile);k(vs.objectbrowser);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2)&rd=true

Comment: Some of the code in this question may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517491/how-do-i-send-folder-with-its-contents-subfolder-files-to-server-client-side